# ViewBag empty in ActionFilter OnActionExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a requirement to log a user's journey through an ASP.NET MVC application. I am using a global ActionFilter and log4net. I need to be able to read values (specifically `ViewBag.Title`) from the ViewBag which have been set in the view. At the moment the ViewBag is coming back empty.

```
public class UserActivityFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            var action = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
            properties.Add("Page.Title", action.ViewBag.Title);
        }
        // Log4net stuff goes here
    }
}
```

My views are generally of the following form:

```
@model Foo.BarViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Application: " + Model.Name;
}

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Is it possible to read values in the ViewBag set in the view?

Comment: Have you tried extending ActionFilterAttribute and overriding OnResultExecuted?

Comment: I tried something very similar - creating a ResultFilter (as opposed to an ActionFilter) but still the same problem. Is it because I set the ViewBag value  in the Razor file?

Comment: Bigfellahull is correct, rather than attempting to implement IActionFilter, you should extend the ActionFilterAttribute and override the OnResultExecuted. That will be called *after* your view has been executed, therefore it will contain everything from the previous actions filters, values from the controller as well as from the Razor file. That's the ticket.